# Who are these "people in black?"

Tags: character-identification, vampire-academy-2022

At the end of the [*Vampire Academy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_Academy_(TV_series)) episode “[Beyond the Wards](https://vampireacademy.fandom.com/wiki/Beyond_the_Wards),” two people dressed in black and wearing sunglasses approach the bodies of two Strigoi killed by Rose and Dimitri. and sprinkle some powder on the bodies causing the dead Strigoi to disappear.

Does anyone know who these figures are supposed to be? The recaps of the episode are no help and the series was not renewed; the moroi woman Rose and Lissa sought only referred to them as "those who come after the Strigoi" and seemed to fear them more than the strigoi themselves.

Answer (score 0):

They are known as the Alchemists. There is a spin-off series by the original author called "Bloodlines" specifically about the Alchemist who helps Rose in Blood Promise, Spirit Bound and Last Sacrifice. Her name is Sydney Sage. I am not sure where the episode "Beyond the Wards" is placed in relation to the books, but the answer to your question in short is that The Alchemists are a group of people who's sole purpose is to dispose of the evidence of Strigoi and in extreme cases even Moroi, in order to keep their existance a secret from the human population.

Comment: Haven't read the books, all I can tell you is Lissa, Rose, Dimitri and Adrian seek out a supposed 'heretic' moroi living among humans to pump her for information about St. Vladimir and spirit magic.

Comment: Well those "people in black" who are more feared than the Strigoi? They are the Alchemists. They are more feared because of their tattoos which give them abilities well beyond those of a human or even a Dhampire, which is what Rose is. And since the Dhampire hunt Strigoi and the Alchemists are much more powerful then they are.... you see where I'm going with that...